# handling unicode in python2

Tags: python, excel, unicode

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import tweepy
 import json
 import re
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print data
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
        print tweet
        saveThis = str(time.time())+'::' + tweet
        saveFile = open("tweetDB3.csv", "a")
        saveFile.write(saveThis)
        saveFile.write("\n")
        saveFile.close()
        return True

    except BaseException, e:
        print "failed ondata,",str(e)
        time.sleep(5)

def on_error(self, status):
    print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())

twitterStream.filter(track = ['오늘'])
```

example of result:

> 1465042178.01::RT @BTS_twt: korea#\ud83c\uddf0\ud83c\uddf7 https://t.co/zwKaGo4Lcj
>   1465042181.76::RT @wdfrog: \ud5e4\ub7f4\ub4dc \uacbd\uc81c\uac00 \uc774\ubc88 \uc77c\ub85c \uc0ac\uacfc\ubb38\uc744
>   \uc62c\ub838\uc9c0\ub9cc \uc774\uc790\ub4e4\uc740 \ubd88\uacfc
>   3\uac1c\uc6d4 \uc804\uc778 3\uc6d4 4\uc77c\uc5d0\ub3c4
>   \uc55e\uc73c\ub85c \uc870\uc2ec\ud558\uaca0\ub2e4\ub294
>   \uc0ac\uacfc\ubb38\uc744 \uc62c\ub9b0 \ubc14 \uc788\ub2e4.
>   \uc77c\uc774 \ucee4\uc9c8\uae4c \uba74\ud53c\ud558\ub294
>   \uac83\uc774\ub2c8 \uc5b8\ub860\uc911\uc7ac\uc704\uc5d0 \ud55c\uce35
>   \uac00\uc5f4\ucc28\uac8c \ubbfc\uc6d0\uc744
>   \ub123\uc74d\uc2dc\ub2e4\nhttps://t.co/Wb\u2026

**Question:**

If I do a twitter API stream through the above code (using Korean characters)
the message above is what is being created in excel file which is shown as unicode.
These unicodes have corresponding Korean characters that can be found by print u'string'
But is it possible to make all these unicodes automatically converted Korean?
I've tried to fix python code and tried to solve within excel but no luck.

Comment: In general, you are better off using the codecs library to .encode(), .decode() and open files with your chosen encoding. You should also read this article about the dangers of the default encoding change you used above to save you headaches later: https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Answer (score 1):

Despite the setdefaultencoding method you can't change default encoding in python 2.7. You should use python 3,  (default encoding is UTF-8 and you can change it)